# no such host error while doing docker build from gitlab CI

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I am trying to build CI pipeline to build and publish my application docker image, however during `build` i am getting following error:

`.gitlab-ci.yml:`

```
image: "docker:dind"

before_script:
  - apk add --update python3 py3-pip
  - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
  - python3 --version
...

docker-build:
  stage: Docker
  script:
  - docker build -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE" .
  - docker ps
```

However, this gets me following error:

```
$ docker build -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE" .
error during connect: Post "http://docker:2375/v1.24/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&shmsize=0&t=registry.gitlab.com%2Fmaven123%2Frest-api&target=&ulimits=null&version=1": dial tcp: lookup docker on 169.254.169.xxx:53: no such host
```

Any idea, whats the issue here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the `docker:dind` service.

The image you should use for the job is the normal `docker:latest` image.

```
image: docker
services:
  - "docker:dind"
variables:  # not strictly needed, depending on runner configuration
  DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
```

Comment: Did not work for me. `ERROR: error during connect: Get "http://docker:2375/_ping": dial tcp: lookup docker on 169.254.169.254:53: no such host`

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski if you're getting this error after configuring the job with the dind service and variables as described, you probably have a different problem. I imagine you might be using a self-hosted runner or host machine that is not configured correctly for this scenario.

Comment: I have only use the two lines, works witout issues
image: docker
services:
  - "docker:dind"

Answer (score 2):

Update your `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` file.

```
[runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "ruby:2.7"
    privileged = true <- change this from false to true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"] <- provide path to docker.sock
    shm_size = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and it was because we pull our image from an internal proxy.  When you do that, the name isn't "docker".  To fix, add an alias:

```
services:
    - name: harbor.example.com/dockerhub-proxy-cache/library/docker:24.0.7-dind
      alias: docker
```

Reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/#accessing-the-services